# How to change the icon in bottombar library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

I needed to add bottom navigation bar in my app, which I was able to do very well using the bottombar library that I found in github.

However, another requirement is to change the icons of the bottombar when I click on it. I have not been able to achieve this. Can anyone help me how can I achieve the

[image: Like on clicking home the home button is green, other wise its not highlighted]

**My implementation is as follows**

```
bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(view,savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.useDarkTheme(false);

        bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_home_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

         @Override
         public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
         switch (menuItemId){
         case R.id.menu_home:
         Snackbar.make(view,"Home tab",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;

         case R.id.menu_to_do:
         Snackbar.make(view,"To Do tab",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;

         case R.id.menu_add_books:
         Snackbar.make(view,"Add",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;

         case R.id.menu_notification:
         Snackbar.make(view,"Notification",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;

         case R.id.menu_profile:
         Snackbar.make(view,"Profile",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;

             }
          }
        });
```

As per a tutorial that i had seen, it said to add a menu and I did in as shown below. This is the exact code that I have used in the my demo.
    Its mentioned in the below snippet.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_home_hdpi"
            android:title="Home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_to_do"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_todo_hdpi"
            android:title="To Do"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_add_books"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_add_hdpi"
            android:title="Add"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_notification"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_notification_hdpi"
            android:title="Notification"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_profile_hdpi"
            android:title="Profile"/>

    </menu>
```

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: I making use of this :- 
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'

Comment: How does your `R.menu.bottom_home_menu` file look?

Comment: I just added the menu file here ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the library to test, but probably you can set for the original icon a StateListDrawable, with different images for different states.

You just need to add this file as drawable and give this xml as Image Background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: THanks for posting this, I have added my menu file above, can you please explain me how to use the one you have mentioned above .

Comment: Create drawable file called icon_home_hdpi_state.xml, copy the XML posted above into it, just changing the names of the icons as needed. Then in your menu file change the icon name to icon_home_hdpi_state.

Comment: Also, hopefully your bottom bar library has a function like setPressed, so that you can keep one item pressed in. If not, add it yourself.